# Scala Split Seq or List by Delimiter

Tags: scala

Let's say I have a sequence of ints like this:

`val mySeq = Seq(0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2)`

I want to split this by let's say 0 as a delimiter to look like this:

`val mySplitSeq = Seq(Seq(0, 1, 2, 1), Seq(0, -1), Seq(0, 1, 2, 3, 2))`

What is the most elegant way to do this in Scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works alright

```
mySeq.foldLeft(Vector.empty[Vector[Int]]) {
  case (acc, i) if acc.isEmpty => Vector(Vector(i))
  case (acc, 0) => acc :+ Vector(0)
  case (acc, i) => acc.init :+ (acc.last :+ i)
}
```

where 0 (or whatever) is your delimiter.

Comment: I guess I should mention that you're not appending anything to a list here.

Comment: It's roughly [`O(n * log(n))`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18724313/2707792) for an obviously linear algorithm... Appending to `Vector` doesn't make it `O(n^2)`, but it's not constant time either.

Comment: No, wait, what? It takes `acc.init` every time it appends an element to a sublist? Then it's not even `O(n*log(n))`, but rather sth. like `O(n^2*log(n)^2)`. That's *not linear*.

Comment: Hmm I had assumed `acc.init` was constant time

Comment: Hm, I don't know, documentation says that `tail` on `Vector` is "essentially constant", in the sense that it's `O(log32(N))`, which is <= 6 on realistic computers. [This here](http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/ScalaVectoroperationsarentEffectivelyConstanttime.html) looks interesting.

Comment: Ha I literally had that article open in another tab. I'm with you that it's not exactly `O(n)` but I think we're likely a lot better than `O(n^2*log(n)^2)`.

Comment: If the leaves look like arrays with up to 32 entries, how do you take `init` and insert a new element at the end without copying all the preceding elements of the array? Remember, it's supposed to be immutable. I don't see how this can be done in constant time. Maybe in constant number of `System.arraycopy` invocations or something like that...

Comment: This would be an interesting separate SO question I suppose. I would be very surprised if `.dropRight` followed by append involved copying the entire preceding `Vector`, though I've been very surprised before.

Comment: The problem is, as soon as you accept such things as "eC", you could simply say that 32 < Infinity, and therefore claim that copying `N-1` out of `N` elements is "essentially constant" as long as `N` stays under 32, which is kind-of ridiculous? I mean, assume that your `acc` has 32 elements, and you append 1000 elements to the 32-th sublist. What is it supposed to do, if not copy the first 31 sublists thousand times?

Comment: It would be N < 2^31, no?  Seems a practical assumption to me. I grant you `O(log(n))` in pure terms!

Comment: What I mean is: `Vector` seems to store 32-element arrays in the leafs. If you have a `Vector` with, say, 10, 20 or 30 elements, I don't see how you can perform the `.init` operation without copying 9 (resp. 19, 29) preceding elements. That is, for small `N` (around 32), it behaves quadratically. If it's quadratic for small `N`, and if we insist that "there are no large N at all" (because of "eC"), then I don't understand what the statement about time complexity is supposed to say at all. How is `~O(N^2)` for small `N` and `O(N*log(N)^2)` for large `N` sum up to give "effectively `O(N)`"?

Comment: *"Bad for small `N`"* + *"Bad for large `N`"* = *"Effectively good for all N"* or what? What kind of analysis is that...

Comment: Where are you getting that large-N complexity?  That said, we should probably shelve this, lest SO keep yelling at me to move it into chat. Worth a separate q I think.

Answer (score 3):

**Efficient O(n) solution**

Tail-recursive solution that never appends anything to lists:

```
def splitBy[A](sep: A, seq: List[A]): List[List[A]] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def rec(xs: List[A], revAcc: List[List[A]]): List[List[A]] = xs match {
    case Nil => revAcc.reverse
    case h :: t => 
      if (h == sep) {
        val (pref, suff) = xs.tail.span(_ != sep)
        rec(suff, (h :: pref) :: revAcc)
      } else {
        val (pref, suff) = xs.span(_ != sep)
        rec(suff, pref :: revAcc)
      }
  }
  rec(seq, Nil)
}

val mySeq = List(0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2)
println(splitBy(0, mySeq))
```

produces:

```
List(List(0, 1, 2, 1), List(0, -1), List(0, 1, 2, 3, 2))
```

It also handles the case where the input does not start with the separator.

---

**For fun: Another O(n) solution that works for small integers**

This is more of warning rather than a solution. Trying to reuse `String`'s `split` does not result in anything sane:

```
val mySeq = Seq(0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2)
val z = mySeq.min
val res = (mySeq
  .map(x => (x - z).toChar)
  .mkString
  .split((-z).toChar)
  .map(s => 0 :: s.toList.map(_.toInt + z)
).toList.tail)
```

It will fail if the integers span a range larger than 65535, and it looks pretty insane. Nevertheless, I find it amusing that it works at all:

```
res: List[List[Int]] = List(List(0, 1, 2, 1), List(0, -1), List(0, 1, 2, 3, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foldLeft`:

```
val delimiter = 0

val res = mySeq.foldLeft(Seq[Seq[Int]]()) {
  case (acc, `delimiter`) => acc :+ Seq(delimiter)
  case (acc, v) => acc.init :+ (acc.last :+ v)
}
```

NOTE: This assumes input necessarily starts with `delimiter`.

Comment: That's a lot of appends with `:+` to an immutable Sequence (which will probably be `List`)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I believe is both short and should run in O(n):

```
def seqSplitter[T](s: ArrayBuffer[T], delimiter : T) = 
  (0 +: s.indices.filter(s(_)==delimiter) :+ s.size)  //find split locations
  .sliding(2)
  .map(idx => s.slice(idx.head, idx.last)) //extract the slice
  .dropWhile(_.isEmpty) //take care of the first element
  .toList
```

The idea is to take all the indices where the delimiter occurs, slide over them and slice the sequence at those locations. `dropWhile` takes care of the first element being a delimiter or not.

Here I am putting all the data in an `ArrayBuffer` to ensure [slicing will take O(size_of_slice)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26803269/2928853).

```
val mySeq = ArrayBuffer(0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2)
seqSplitter(mySeq, 0).toList
```

Gives:

```
List(ArrayBuffer(0, 1, 2, 1), ArrayBuffer(0, -1), ArrayBuffer(0, 1, 2, 3, 2))
```

### A more detailed complexity analysis

The operations are:

- Filter the delimiter indices (O(n))
- loop over a list of indices obtained from previous step (O(num_of_delimeters)); for each pair of indices corresponding to a slice:

  - Copy the slice from the array and put it into the final collection (O(size_of_slice))

The last two steps sum up to O(n).

Comment: 1) Empty list at the start. 2) All `0`s missing in the output.

Comment: The question provided the expected output: `val mySplitSeq = Seq(Seq(0, 1, 2, 1), Seq(0, -1), Seq(0, 1, 2, 3, 2))`, so there's no ambiguity there. The OP didn't specify what should happen if the input does not start with the delimiter - that was the only ambiguity that I see there. On performance: if the actual underlying immutable sequence is `List`, then each `:+` would rebuild the entire list, which would result in `O(n^2)` runtime *assuming* that the subsequences remain "short" for `N -> infty`. That is a bit weird for a blatantly `O(n)` algorithm...

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, I rewrote my answer to address those issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One more variant using indices and reverse slicing

```
scala> val s = Seq(0,1, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2)
s: scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2)

scala> s.indices.filter( s(_)==0).+:(if(s(0)!=0) -1 else -2).filter(_>= -1 ).reverse.map( {var p=0; x=>{ val y=s.slice(x,s.size-p);p=s.size-x;y}}).reverse
res173: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int]] = Vector(ArrayBuffer(0, 1, 2, 1), ArrayBuffer(0, -1), ArrayBuffer(0, 1, 2, 3, 2))
```

if the starting doesn't have the delimiter, then also it works.. thanks to jrook

```
scala>  val s = Seq(1, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2)
s: scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2)

scala> s.indices.filter( s(_)==0).+:(if(s(0)!=0) -1 else -2).filter(_>= -1 ).reverse.map( {var p=0; x=>{ val y=s.slice(x,s.size-p);p=s.size-x;y}}).reverse
res174: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int]] = Vector(ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 1), ArrayBuffer(0, -1), ArrayBuffer(0, 1, 2, 3, 2))
```

**UPDATE1:**

More compact version by removing the "reverse" in above

```
scala> val s = Seq(0,1, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2)
s: scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2)

scala> s.indices.filter( s(_)==0).+:(if(s(0)!=0) -1 else -2).filter(_>= -1 ).:+(s.size).sliding(2,1).map( x=>s.slice(x(0),x(1)) ).toList
res189: List[scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int]] = List(ArrayBuffer(0, 1, 2, 1), ArrayBuffer(0, -1), ArrayBuffer(0, 1, 2, 3, 2))

scala> val s = Seq(1, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2)
s: scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2)

scala> s.indices.filter( s(_)==0).+:(if(s(0)!=0) -1 else -2).filter(_>= -1 ).:+(s.size).sliding(2,1).map( x=>s.slice(x(0),x(1)) ).toList
res190: List[scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int]] = List(ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 1), ArrayBuffer(0, -1), ArrayBuffer(0, 1, 2, 3, 2))

scala>
```

Comment: This drops the first sequence if the list does not start with the delimiter

Comment: '@jrook.. yes.. let me fix that

Comment: `sliding(2,1)` is equivalent to `sliding(2)`