# How to convert a list to list of lists by group the elements when an element repeats in Scala idiomatic way

Tags: scala, list, functional-programming

I want to convert a list of elements into a list of lists by breaking whenever an element repeats like below

**Input:**

```
List(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3)
```

**Ouput:**

```
List[List[Integer]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2), List(1, 3), List(1, 2, 3))
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
val tokens = List(1,2,3,1,2,1,3,1,2,3)

val group = new ListBuffer[List[Integer]]()
val nextGroup = new ListBuffer[Integer]()
val nextTokens = new ListBuffer[Integer]()

for (t <- tokens) {
  if (nextTokens.contains(t)) {
    group += nextGroup.toList
    nextGroup.clear()
    nextTokens.clear()
  }
  nextGroup += t
  nextTokens += t
}

group += nextGroup.toList

group.toList
```

I'm looking for a better way to achieve this using map/foldLeft... functions without using ListBuffer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you are separating the list whenever there is a 1?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52976568/scala-split-seq-or-list-by-delimiter/52977170#52977170

Comment: In my case, element 1 is not fixed. I want to break the list whenever I encounter a repeated element.

Comment: @jrook This question is not a duplicate of the question you posted as in my scenario there is no fixed delimiter.

Comment: Thanks @jrook Reference to the similar question helped in coming up with the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the solution provided for below question, I have come up with the below  solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52976957/1696418

```
mySeq.foldLeft(List.empty[List[Int]]) {
  case (acc, i) if acc.isEmpty => List(List(i))
  case (acc, i) if acc.last.contains(i) => acc :+ List(i)
  case (acc, i) => acc.init :+ (acc.last :+ i)
}
```

Comment: This is going to perform badly if the list is long because `last` and `init` require a search of the whole list, and you check `isEmpty` every time even though it is only an issue for the first element.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using `foldLeft`

```
tokens
  .drop(1)
  .foldLeft(List(tokens.take(1))) { case (res, token) =>
    if (res.head.contains(token)) {
      List(token) +: res
    } else {
      (res.head :+ token) +: res.tail
    }
  }
  .reverse
```

Using `drop` and `take` ensures that this works on an empty list. Building the result in reverse means that the latest `List` is always at the head, and will also be efficient for long lists.

And for completeness, here is a recursive function that does the same thing:

```
def groupDistinct[T](tokens: List[T]): List[List[T]] = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(token: List[T], cur: List[T], res: List[List[T]]): List[List[T]] =
    token match {
      case Nil =>
        res :+ cur
      case head :: tail =>
        if (cur.contains(head)) {
          loop(tail, List(head), res :+ cur)
        } else {
          loop(tail, cur :+ head, res)
        }
    }

  loop(tokens, Nil, Nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very direct solution which uses `foldLeft` while keeping track of two accumulator arrays: One for the final result, and one for the currently considered token sublist. Finally, we combine the result array with the last sublist.

```
val (acc, last) = tokens.foldLeft ((List[List[Int]](), List[Int]())) ((a,b) =>
            if (a._2.contains(b)) (a._1 :+ a._2, List(b))
            else (a._1, a._2 :+ b))
acc :+ last
```

Notice that this is not the computationally most efficient solution, since for each iteration we are checking through the entire sublist under consideration using `contains`. If you wish for efficiency, you might (depending on your data) consider an approach which uses hash maps or similar data structures instead for faster repetition checks.